# How can I convert an Integer datatype columns value into datetime in SQL Server

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I have the table as in the attached screenshot and I want to concatenate the `logdate` and `logtime` integer columns and convert them into datetime

```
logdate  | logtime
20200501 |   90205
20200502 |  100215
20200503 |  110105
```

like `'2020-05-01 09:02:05'` for the first example.

Comment: Do you want a text type result or a datetime type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up a valid date string, then [`convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it:

```
select
    convert (datetime, concat(
        substring(cast(logdate as char(8)), 1, 4), '-', 
        substring(cast(logdate as char(8)), 5, 2), '-', 
        substring(cast(logdate as char(8)), 7, 2), ' ',
        substring(right('000000' + cast(logtime as varchar(6)), 6), 1, 2), ':', 
        substring(right('000000' + cast(logtime as varchar(6)), 6), 3, 2), ':', 
        substring(right('000000' + cast(logtime as varchar(6)), 6), 5, 2)
    ) as timestamp
from ...
```

Comment: `substr` ? or you mean `substring` ?

Comment: @Squirrel yes, thx. Plus some other stuff needed to build a train wreck